# Add your own vocabulary [Nuxeo]

Tags: java, seam, ecm, nuxeo

I'm writing a layout contribution, I added a suggestOneDirectory widget named city but I don't know where can I change/add my own directoryName (instead of l10ncoverage) that contains the vocabulary of cities to be shown on the list.

```
 <widget name="city" type="suggestOneDirectory">
    <labels>
      <label mode="any">City :</label>
    </labels>
    <translated>true</translated>
    <fields>
      <field>adr:city</field>
    </fields>
    <properties mode="any">
      <property name="width">300</property>
      <property name="labelFieldName">label_{lang}</property>
      <property name="dbl10n">true</property>
      <property name="minChars">0</property>
      <property name="hideHelpLabel">true</property>
      <property name="directoryName">l10ncoverage</property>
      <property name="keySeparator">/</property>
      <property name="placeholder">Ville</property>
      <property name="documentSchemas">dublincore,layout_demo_schema</property>
      <property name="repository">default</property>
    </properties>
    <controls mode="any">
      <!-- enable ajax submit on change/click/select on demo application -->
      <control name="supportInsideInputWidgetEffects">true</control>
    </controls>
  </widget>
```

I'm not using Nuxeo Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it from the Admin Center: see [USERDOC/Managing+Vocabularies](https://doc.nuxeo.com/x/VYEk)

Or you can use an extension point: see [SQLDirectoryFactory--directories](http://explorer.nuxeo.com/nuxeo/site/distribution/current/viewExtensionPoint/org.nuxeo.ecm.directory.sql.SQLDirectoryFactory--directories)

Comment: I combined the two links to override l10ncoverage directory. What if I want to create a new directory and not just override the existing ones, is that possible? Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: The above extension point not only overrides existing directories, it also creates new ones.